# Can I provide defaults for a subclass of a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to create a class hierarchy, where all objects of class `Base` has a field `field1`, but different subclasses have different default values for `field1`. The classes are data holders, so `dataclasses` seems like the perfect library to use.

Consider the following python 3.7+ code.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Iterable

@dataclass
class Base:
    field1: Iterable[Any]

@dataclass
class Sub(Base):
    field2: Any
    field1: Iterable[Any] = field(default_factory=list)
```

The code fails, giving me `TypeError: non-default argument 'field2' follows default argument`. This is a little surprising, since `field2` follows the non-default `field1` of the superclass, and the defalt argument `field1` of the class `Sub` actually comes after `field2`.

According to the example in [the docs on dataclass inheritence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#inheritance) though, fields in subclasses overrides the fields in superclasses, but field order is preserved. So the error makes sense.

Is there any suitable workaround here, or must I implement everything by hand?

Comment: Well, the easiest way around it is adding a default value to field2. If this is not okay for you, maybe declare field2 as an InitVar and raise an exception in post init if the field is not initialized. `field2: Any = None` should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @property decorator:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Iterable

@dataclass
class Base:
    @property
    def field1(self) -> Iterable[Any]:
        return

@dataclass
class Sub(Base):
    field2: Any

    @property
    def field1(self) -> Iterable[Any]:
        return []  # or whatever default you want to put here
```